# Can command-line set Java system properties be distinguished from the defaults?

Tags: java

Is there a way to distinguish a Java system property which has been set from the command line using a `-D` option from a system property which got the same value by default?

E.g., this program

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
  }
}
```

prints

```
/home/uckelman
```

for me regardless of whether I run it as

```
java Test
```

or

```
java -Duser.home=/home/uckelman Test
```

Is there anything which the JDK provides which I could test to distinguish these two situations?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `-D` indicates user intentionality, even if it does match the default.

Comment: Right, and how do you plan to use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to get the command line arguments used to start the JVM and check the returned List if a given system property is set or not.

```
RuntimeMXBean mx = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
System.out.println("COMMAND LINE ARGS:\n" + mx.getInputArguments());
```